# Generic Filter and Sort Using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Is there a way to implement Generic filter for NHibernate on a repository layer? As per Microsoft API Guidelines, the sort and filters are passed as string [API Guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#9-collections). what will be the approach to that using NHibernate to make it generic?

Comment: The guidelines that I mentioned passes fields and values. I don't see any reason why implementing generic filters can be harmful in this case since we are using NHibernate

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have or what you are trying to achive

Comment: Without the bounty this question will get closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this post](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-nhibernate/).There is a section **Paging with NHibernate**.
The code snippet below is from this post.

The approach is to implement a class (in the post it was `PagedResult<T>`) in your case `FilteredResult<T>`. Having this class you can implementan extension (in post was `NHibernatePagedResultExtensions`) in this case `NHibernateFilteredResultExtensions`.

And the last thing left is to apply this extansion exacly the same way.
Hope this will help.

```
public abstract class PagedResultBase
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public int PageCount { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public string LinkTemplate { get; set; }

    public int FirstRowOnPage
    {

        get { return (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize + 1; }
    }

    public int LastRowOnPage
    {
        get { return Math.Min(CurrentPage * PageSize, RowCount); }
    }
}

public class PagedResult<T> : PagedResultBase
{
    public IList<T> Results { get; set; }

    public PagedResult()
    {
        Results = new List<T>();
    }
}


public static class NHibernatePagedResultExtensions
{
    public static async Task<PagedResult<T>> GetPagedAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        var result = new PagedResult<T>
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            RowCount = query.Count()
        };

        var pageCount = (double)result.RowCount / pageSize;
        result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);

        var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        result.Results = await query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
}



public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
{
    var result = await _session.RunInTransaction(async () =>
    {
        var books = await _session.Books
                                    .Where(b => b.Title.StartsWith("How to"))
                                    .GetPagedAsync(page, pageSize: 25);
        return _mapper.Map<PagedResult<BookModel>>(books);
    });

    return View(result);
}
```